# Массивы в языке программирования C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Дан массив из `n` чисел. Заполните массив случайными числами из диапазона,
границы которого выберите самостоятельно и выполните следующие задания в классе:

> Определить минимальный элемент и его порядковый номер.

Comment: День добрый. С чем конкретно проблемы возникли? За вас полностью ваше домашнее задание никто делать не будет)

Answer (score 1):

Дан массив из `n` чисел... Пусть `n` - это `10`:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n];
```

Границы диапазона выберите самостоятельно...

```
int m = 0, M = 100;
```

Заполните массив случайными числами

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr[i] = rand%(M-m+1)+m;
```

Ищем минимальный элемент `min` и его номер `j`:

```
int j = 0, min = arr[0];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arr[i] < min) {
        min = arr[i];
        j = i;
    }
```

Ну а выведите их вы уже самостоятельно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @ВладиславБирюков если вопрос вам помог, отметьте его как принятый. Галочка слева от ответа.